# Possible error in textbook (Lorentz transformation)

Tags: special-relativity

I'm concerned about the last line of this page.

[image: Lorentz transformation]

I believe it should be: "With the help of a friend in $S'$, the $S$ observer also measures the distance from the event to the origin of $S'$ and finds it to be $x'\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$."

Could someone please confirm?

This is the URL of the page: https://cnx.org/contents/rydUIGBQ@12.20:wi8weztM@7/5-5-The-Lorentz-Transformation

Comment: There is no mistake, moving objects get contracted!

Comment: In the S (not the S') frame, the moving length is x', which thereby gets contracted by the Lorentz factor. But the text says the reverse.

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you are right and there is a typo in the text. The length contraction happens for $x^\prime$ from the viewpoint of $S$, and $S^\prime$ can never detect any length contraction for the lengths at rest in his own frame of reference.